# How do I get rid of the commands (for, do, if …) in Algorithmic?

Tags: algorithms

I am writing a paper in LATEX like the picture. I tried many times but there I haven't yet shown the way to do them.  [image]

I tried to type this example with Algorithm but it can not. Could you say to me a hint for my problem? Thanks alls!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regular `tabular`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand{\algvrule}{@{\hspace{.5em}}|@{\hspace{1em}}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{} l @{}}
  As before,~$k$ here is a commutative ring. \\
  \begin{tabular}{\algvrule l @{}}
    Hence could be a field of integers~$Z$; these are the usual choices. \\
    \begin{tabular}{\algvrule l @{}}
      Given an infinite variable set $x = (x_1; x_2; \ldots)$, a monomial \\
      $x^p = x_1^a x_2^b \cdots$, is indexed by an element $t = (a; b; \ldots)$ in~$N^\infty$ \\
      having finite support, such~$t$ are called weak compositions.
    \end{tabular} \\
    The nonzero ones among the integers $a; b; \ldots$ are called the parts of the
  \end{tabular} \\
  weak composition~$t$.
\end{tabular}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your nice solve @Werner!

Comment: @CaoLu If Werner's answer helps you, please accept it by (1) upvote the answer and (2) click the tick right below the vote icons.

Comment: @JouleV Thank you so much. Yes, of course, I will vote soon to his nice solution. However, my account is not enough to do that now :))